# Find the image of the set $\{z \in \mathbb C | -3\lt Re(z) \lt 5, -1 \lt Im(z) \lt 6 \}$, under the function $e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the image of the set $\{z \in \mathbb C | -3\lt Re(z) \lt 5, -1 \lt Im(z) \lt 6 \}$, under the function $e^z$

So I know that I should like it as $e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos(y)+i \sin(y))$. And I think that that it somehow describes a section of the unit circle. How to I continue though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not a section of the unit circle. You must know that the image of the set 
$$
\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : Im(z)=a \} 
$$
under $e^z$ is the line on the complex plane with argument=$a$. And the image of the set 
$$
\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : Re(z)=b \} 
$$
under $e^z$ is the circle in the complex plane with radius=$e^b$. Can you follow from here?

Comment: I think you mean with radius $e^b$ for the image of the second set.

Comment: @TorsionSquid Indeed ! Thnks

Answer (score 0):

Think in terms of polar coordinates.  The exponential map takes $x+iy$ to a point with modulus $e^x$ and argument $y$.  So if $-3<Re(z)<5$, then $e^{-3}<|e^z|<e^5$.  Similarly, $-1<Im(z)<6$ implies $-1<arg(e^z)<6$.  In short, the image is an annulus. (We get the full annulus rather than a sector since $6+1=7>2\pi$.)